# Read an existing CSV & copy columns 0, 6 and 9 to a new CSV

Tags: python, csv

I am running Spyder (Python 3.8) and have a large csv with 10 columns (do you call them columns like excel?). I need to copy 3 columns from it into a new csv. I've written the following which successfully copies everything but I cannot figure out how to only copy specific multiple columns like 0, 6 & 9.

```
import csv
with open('new.csv' ,'w') as outFile:
    fileWriter = csv.writer(outFile)
    with open('existing.csv','r') as inFile:
        fileReader = csv.reader(inFile)
        for row in fileReader:
            fileWriter.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`row` is a list of values that you can access by using indexing, like any other list.

See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists.

To write only specific columns to the output file, replace `row` with a new list containing the desired values:

```
for row in fileReader:
    fileWriter.writerow([row[0], row[6], row[9]])
```